# JavaScript does not work when I put it on the server

Tags: javascript, html, server, onload

I have a code that when I run it from any part of the PC without putting it on the server it works perfectly, but when I put it on the server and I call it, it gives me the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: crearLienzo is not defined
    at onload ((index):81)

I do not understand why this happens. Thank you all!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var movimientos = new Array();
    var pulsado;
    function crearLienzo() {
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('lienzo');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', 200);
canvas.setAttribute('height', 200);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
      pulsado = true;
      movimientos.push([e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
          e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
          false]);
      repinta();
    });

    $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
      if(pulsado){
          movimientos.push([e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
              e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
              true]);
        repinta();
      }
    });

    $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
      pulsado = false;
    });

    $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
      pulsado = false;
    });
    repinta();

}


    function repinta() {
        // función para dibujar en el lienzo los movimientos del ratón que hemos
        // recogido en la variable "movimientos"
         canvas.width = canvas.width; // Limpia el lienzo

  context.strokeStyle = "#0000a0";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 6;

  for(var i=0; i < movimientos.length; i++)
  {     
    context.beginPath();
    if(movimientos[i][2] && i){
      context.moveTo(movimientos[i-1][0], movimientos[i-1][1]);
     }else{
      context.moveTo(movimientos[i][0], movimientos[i][1]);
     }
     context.lineTo(movimientos[i][0], movimientos[i][1]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
       var image = new Image();
       image.src = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
        alert(image);
       return image;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background: #eee;" onload="crearLienzo()">
<div id="lienzo" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #fff;"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="convertCanvasToImage($('#canvas'));">aa</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser? What server? Do you have jquery embedded in webapp since you refer to server resource? You have typos in code (e.g. `getElemenatById`) so does it realy work? Why you are using bare DOM manipuation functions (getElementById) if you are having jQuery? Why are not you building it directly in web-enabled tools, like jsfiddle (that would show you one error by another in your code)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put your script tag inside body to load it first

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body style="background: #eee;" onload="crearLienzo()">
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var movimientos = new Array();
        var pulsado;
        function crearLienzo() {
        var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('lienzo');
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', 200);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', 200);
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
    canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
    if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
          pulsado = true;
          movimientos.push([e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
              e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
              false]);
          repinta();
        });

        $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
          if(pulsado){
              movimientos.push([e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
                  e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
                  true]);
            repinta();
          }
        });

        $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
          pulsado = false;
        });

        $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
          pulsado = false;
        });
        repinta();

    }


        function repinta() {
            // función para dibujar en el lienzo los movimientos del ratón que hemos
            // recogido en la variable "movimientos"
             canvas.width = canvas.width; // Limpia el lienzo

      context.strokeStyle = "#0000a0";
      context.lineJoin = "round";
      context.lineWidth = 6;

      for(var i=0; i < movimientos.length; i++)
      {     
        context.beginPath();
        if(movimientos[i][2] && i){
          context.moveTo(movimientos[i-1][0], movimientos[i-1][1]);
         }else{
          context.moveTo(movimientos[i][0], movimientos[i][1]);
         }
         context.lineTo(movimientos[i][0], movimientos[i][1]);
         context.closePath();
         context.stroke();
      }
    }
    function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
           var image = new Image();
           image.src = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
            alert(image);
           return image;
    }
    </script>
    <div id="lienzo" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #fff;"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="convertCanvasToImage($('#canvas'));">aa</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "Put your script tag inside body to load it first" — Putting it in the body instead of the head will cause it to load **later**. How does this solve the problem?

Comment: I got solution by running this code for that answer I posted.But sorry for statement  
"Put your script tag inside body to load it first"

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly with your solution!

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery library from googleapis library. Include your script tag before the end of the body tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: #eee;" onload="crearLienzo()">
<div id="lienzo" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #fff;"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="convertCanvasToImage($('#canvas'));">aa</button>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var movimientos = new Array();
    var pulsado;
    function crearLienzo() { alert('hea');
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('lienzo');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', 200);
canvas.setAttribute('height', 200);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
      pulsado = true;
      movimientos.push([e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
          e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
          false]);
      repinta();
    });

    $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
      if(pulsado){
          movimientos.push([e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
              e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
              true]);
        repinta();
      }
    });

    $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
      pulsado = false;
    });

    $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
      pulsado = false;
    });
    repinta();

}


    function repinta() {
        // función para dibujar en el lienzo los movimientos del ratón que hemos
        // recogido en la variable "movimientos"
         canvas.width = canvas.width; // Limpia el lienzo

  context.strokeStyle = "#0000a0";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 6;

  for(var i=0; i < movimientos.length; i++)
  {     
    context.beginPath();
    if(movimientos[i][2] && i){
      context.moveTo(movimientos[i-1][0], movimientos[i-1][1]);
     }else{
      context.moveTo(movimientos[i][0], movimientos[i][1]);
     }
     context.lineTo(movimientos[i][0], movimientos[i][1]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
       var image = new Image();
       image.src = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
        alert(image);
       return image;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This way it will work everywhere. Also as script tag is included at the end of the body tag, it will load after all the css and image files are loaded.

Comment: "Use jQuery library from googleapis library" — Why? The question says the error message is about `crearLienzo` not `$`

Comment: On debugging the code, the function (crearLienzo) gets called perfectly if it is included before the end of body tag on server. Moreover, it is a bad practice to download the jquery library and load it on server. You should definitely load it from Hosted Libraries.